# Remote Network Wake up Windows computer for backup

Tags: windows, backup

What is the most efficient way to remotely wake up a Windows computer over a LAN for a backup operation without resorting to third party software?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question.  I should had specified that I wish the wakeup to be remotely controlled through the LAN rather than configured locally.